# Python regexp (sre_constants.error: unmatched group)

Tags: python, regex

I checked all the related post on Stackoverflow, but none of the answers helped. I have the following items in a list:

```
topics\Utmutatok\Uzemeltetoi_Utmutato.dita
topics\_Reuse\Definitions\FRP_CUST_PROD_properties.xml
topics\_Reuse\Definitions\FRP_properties.xml
topics\_Reuse\Definitions\FR_Definitions.dita
```

I use the following lines in my python file:

```
kifejezes5 = re.sub(r'^(?!(?:topics/_Reuse(.*?)|^$)$|$).*$', r'@@@@@.\1', kifejezes4)
```

The expressions work perfectly in Notepad++, but not in my script.

When I run my script I get the error mentioned in the title. Is there any possible workaround here?

Comment: What do you think `?!` and `\1` mean?

Comment: You have a capturing group inside a negative lookahead. The group will never be populated, otherwise, there would be no match.

Comment: Please explain what output you need to get, say, for `topics\_Reuse\Definitions\FRP_CUST_PROD_properties.xml`?

Comment: the output should be: `@@@@@topics\_Reuse\Definitions\FRP_CUST_PROD_properties.xml`

Comment: So, `re.sub(r'^(?!(?:topics/_Reuse.*)?$).*$', r'@@@@@\g<0>', s)`?

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem!

Comment: Please consider checking the answer with explanations below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group is unmatched because the capturing group is used inside a negative lookahead. If there is a match, the group is never populated.

Instead, use

```
re.sub(r'^(?!(?:topics/_Reuse.*)?$).*$', r'@@@@@\g<0>', s)
```

See the [online Python demo](http://ideone.com/YSNh7p):

```
import re
s = 'topics\_Reuse\Definitions\FRP_CUST_PROD_properties.xml'
res = re.sub(r'^(?!(?:topics/_Reuse.*)?$).*$', r'@@@@@\g<0>', s)
print(res)
# => @@@@@topics\_Reuse\Definitions\FRP_CUST_PROD_properties.xml
```

The  pattern matches:

- `^`  - start of string
- `(?!(?:topics/_Reuse.*)?$)` - not followed with `topics/_Reuse` and then any 0+ chars up to the end of string OR just the end of string (the string cannot be empty)
- `.*$` - any 0+ chars (other than line break chars) up to the end of string.

The replacement pattern contains a `\g<0>` backreference to the whole match.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! I misunderstood the backreferencing.... Now it's OK!